# Contravariance of delegate resulting in error of "Cannot convert from ... to ..."

Tags: c#, delegates, contravariance

In order to simplify, let say I have a parent and a child class:

```
public class MyParent { }
public class MyChild : MyParent { }
```

And this two function with some code:

```
public void DoSomethingBy_MyChild(MyChild myChild) { //code }
public void DoSomethingBy_MyParent(MyParent myParent) { //code }
```

But when I try this unit test of `Action<MyChild>` delegate with `DoSomethingBy_MyParent` with a `MyParent` param the compiler says:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MyParent' to 'MyChild'.

```
public void UnitTest()
{            
    Action<MyChild> processor;
    processor = DoSomethingBy_MyChild;
    processor(new MyChild());             //OK

    processor = DoSomethingBy_MyParent; 
    processor(new MyChild());             //OK

    processor = DoSomethingBy_MyParent;
    processor(new MyParent());            //Error
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Using Variance in Delegates (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/using-variance-in-delegates):

> When you assign a method to a delegate, *covariance* and *contravariance* provide flexibility for matching a delegate type with a method signature. Covariance permits a method to have return type that is more derived than that defined in the delegate. Contravariance permits a method that has parameter types that are less derived than those in the delegate type.

---

It is fine to assign `DoSomethingBy_MyParent` to `processor` (a *contravariant* assignment since `MyParent` is less-derived than `MyChild`) because anything which is `MyChild` is, by definition also `MyParent`:

```
Action<MyChild> processor;
processor = DoSomethingBy_MyParent;
```

However, what happens when you then try to pass a `MyParent` into `processor` is effectively

```
Action<MyChild> processor;
processor(new MyParent());
```

This is not fine because `processor` requires a `MyChild` to be passed into it - it cannot be *called* contravariantly. It doesn't matter that you've assigned `DoSomethingBy_MyParent` to it - `processor` is declared as `Action<MyChild>` so it **must** receive an instance of `MyChild` or a more-derived type.

---

To put it another way, you have

```
public void DoSomethingBy_MyChild(MyChild myChild) { //code }
```

and you wouldn't expect to be able to call it like this:

```
DoSomethingBy_MyChild(new Parent());
```

because method calls work covariantly (you can pass in an instance of a more-derived type), not contravariantly (you cannot pass in an instance of a less-derived type).

Comment: it won't compile. It will give you `CS0123 No overload for 'DoSomethingBy_MyChild' matches delegate '` error

Comment: @rraszewski - of course, you are right. I've removed the incorrect portion of my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

That might help [Action delegates, generics, covariance and contravariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904805/action-delegates-generics-covariance-and-contravariance)

Basically, all is good. `Action<T>` is contravariant, so you can assign `DoSomethingBy_MyParent` to `Action<MyChild> processor`. This is contravariance.

But since `processor` is of type `Action<MyChild>` you cannot call it with `MyParent` instance.